# How to store multiple data and merge it in one reference in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to post the results from scanned data and the Image file captured to store it in the firebase real-time database using one reference. So far, I can store the scanned data to the database in a list when I click the 'save' button, so I wanted also to merge other data into all one reference. The 'capture an image' button opens up a new page for capturing an image. The 'Add Another item' button just allows scanning for another type of barcode. Check my code below class BarcodesResultPreviewWidget.

```
class BarcodesResultPreviewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  BarcodeScanningResult preview;
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('ScannedResults');





  //Retrieving the data on console
  void getData(){
    databaseRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      values.forEach((key,values) {
        print(values["ScannedItem"]);

      });
    });

  }

  BarcodesResultPreviewWidget(this.preview);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget previewView;
    //Initialize FlutterFire
    //Firebase.initializeApp();
    var barcodeImageURI = preview.barcodeImageURI;
    if (barcodeImageURI != null) {
      if (shouldInitWithEncryption) {
        previewView = EncryptedPageWidget(barcodeImageURI);
      } else {
        previewView = PageWidget(barcodeImageURI);
      }
    } else {
      previewView = Container();
    }
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(),
          leading: GestureDetector(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: const Text('Scanned barcodes',
              style: TextStyle(inherit: true, color: Colors.black)),
        ),
        body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        previewView,
        //printing scanned results
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: preview.barcodeItems.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return BarcodeItemWidget(preview.barcodeItems[position]);

              },


          ),

        ),
        Wrap(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Text('Add Another Item',),
                onPressed: () {

                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => MainPageWidget()),
                  );


                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Text('Capture an Image',),
                onPressed: () {

                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => TakePictureScreen(title: '',)) ,
                  );


                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Text('Save',),
                onPressed: () {
                  // databaseRef.push().set({
                  //   'ScannedItem': Map.fromIterable(preview.barcodeItems,
                  //       key: (item) => preview.barcodeItems.indexOf(item),
                  //       value: (item) => item.toJson()),
                  // });
                  databaseRef.push().set({
                    'ScannedItem': preview.barcodeItems
                        .map((barCodeItem) => barCodeItem.toJson())
                        .toList().toString().split('%'),
                  });

                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),


      ],

    ));

  }


}
```

Capture an Image class

```
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  TakePictureScreen({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _TakePictureScreenState createState() => _TakePictureScreenState();
}

class _TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  final photos = <File>[];

  void openCamera() {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => CameraCamera(
              onFile: (file) {
                photos.add(file);
                Navigator.pop(context);
                setState(() {});
              },
            )));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemCount: photos.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            width: size.width,
            child: Image.file(
              photos[index],
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: openCamera,
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To update an existing node in the database, you'll need to know the complete path to that node. So you will need to:

1. Keep the key of each node in your `getData` function, and add it to the widget tree, so that you can use it later.
2. Find the relevant key in your `onPressed` when you want to update the node.
3. Then you can update the specific node with something like:

   ```
    databaseRef.child(keyThatYouKept).update({
        'ScannedItem': preview.barcodeItems
            .map((barCodeItem) => barCodeItem.toJson())
            .toList().toString().split('%'),
   ```

You'll need to modify this code to get the key from step 1 and 2 still in there.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your response, may you please assist with how to get the key, meaning your step 1 and step 2. I am still new to Flutter

Comment: You already have the keys here: `values.forEach((key,values) {`. It is unclear to me how the rendered data relates to the database you want to update though, which is why I can't show you how to modify the code more than I've already done.

Comment: Hi Frank, I want be able to pass data from the listview to TakePictureScreen page then take the image file captured and the data retrieved and store to Firebase Realtime database under one reference